# Pointer alingment and array with length storage

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, memory-management

I have found a following implementation of an array that has its length stored "inside" it. Here's the code:

```
double* construct(const size_t nElements)
{
  double* arr = malloc(sizeof(double) * nElements + sizeof(int));
  int i = 0;

  *(int*)arr = nElements;
  ((int*)arr)++;

  for (i = 0; i < nElements; i++) arr[i] = 1.0 * i;      

  return arr;
}

void destroy(double* arr)
{
  free((int*)arr - 1);
}

void print(double* arr)
{
  int N = *((int*)arr - 1);
  int i = 0;

  printf("Supplied array of %d elements:\n", N);

  for (i = 0; i < N; i++) printf("%d : %f\n", i, arr[i]);      
}

int main(void)
{
  double* a = construct(10);

  print(a);    
  destroy(a);

  return 0;
}
```

The idea behind this technique was to allocate a memory block with additional space to store the length of an array, and give user only pointer where actual data starts. However, *I suspect something fishy in this particular implementation in terms of pointer casts (from double* to int*).

Is this allowed in general?

If yes, how does it work in terms of pointer alignment?

Is there a better approach?

*Update:*
Just to clarify, I see that this code is a "hack" and I understand that this is bad. I just want to know what can break and why.

A little summary of given answers:
line `((int*)arr)++;`

1) is ill-formed an compiles only under MSVS

2) makes a sizeof(int) offset which causes the following addresses to be misaligned by double boundary.

This is quite clear, but raises another question: is the cast itself from double* to int* allowed? Does it affect alingment in any way?

Comment: This is a terrible hack. Use a `struct` with _flexible array member_.

Comment: This is certainly questionable. However, you could simply have a struct with an integer representing the size (use `size_t` for this), and a flexible array member of `double`.

Comment: The double array might not be correctly aligned. Other than than, the code seems to be defined. Maybe the pointer arithmetic should have been done using unsigned char.

Comment: why `double` anyway?

Comment: @EugeneSh. No idea, it just was like this.

Comment: when you do `((int*)arr)++; ` arr is no longer aligned for double, at least not guaranteed. `arr++;` is better, but still it's overall bad code.

Comment: `((int*)arr)++;` is ill-formed; `++` may only be applied to an lvalue. Maybe you meant `arr = (double *)((int *)arr + 1);`

Comment: @M.M I have no idea, I just copy-pasted the functions I found. The only thing written by me is main(). I may assume that original author intended to do exactly what you wrote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code you've posted is not valid.  The reason is simple: `malloc()` returns memory aligned for the largest common type on the machine, which is enough for `double`, but then the returned memory is used to store `double`s after a single `int`.  On platforms where `double` is 64 bits and `int` is 32 bits (which is pretty common), this is not valid code, and may crash or exhibit worse performance than expected.

Comment: Could you please elaborate the point why this code is not valid (I suspected as much, but don't know either the reasons, nor the techincal details)?

Comment: @HighPredator because skipping an `int` which is smaller than the `double` means the doubles in the array are misalinged now, at least skip a whole `double`'s worth or in general: skip the same amount of bytes that the type you're allocating would be aligned to (or the `int` whichever is larger`)

Comment: @BeyelerStudios [s]how so?[/s] I will rephrase: what if the "doubles" were misaligned in the first place (e.g. original pointer was aligned by int boundary)? Or that is the effect of the frist assignment to double pointer (after allocation)?

Comment: @BeyelerStudios: There are not necessarily missaligned accesses to the `doubles`. That depends on the platform.

Comment: @HighPredator that must not happen because `malloc` will ensure the returned memory is aligned correctly for any type incl. `double`.

Comment: @HighPredator `malloc()` returns memory suitably aligned for all types. If you store an `int` in front, that may no longer hold.